# how do I change bulkloader.yaml on appengine

Tags: database, google-app-engine, cmd, data-migration, bulkloader

in all tutorials and videos people create bulkloader.yaml on the url XYZ.appengine.com and then change the kind and connector in the file using Notepad. My question: How do they access this created file to change it?
All the best,
Supertyp

Comment: You specify the output filename on the command line. It will be created on your local disk and then you just open it with your text editor from your file manager (Explorer or whatever). Or is that not what you're asking?